# Jquery Cycle activeClass only works after nav is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, cycle

**Updated** - Added onAfter function

I'm having a strange issue with cycle.

The Issue i'm having, is that the "activeSlide" class, doesn't get appended to the pager buttons until you click on one. It works fine when the pager items are clicked, but on page load, when the slider starts rolling through, it stays on the first pager item.

Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            timeout: 4000,
            pause: 1,
            pager: '#nav_slide',
            prev:   '#prev_btn', 
            next:   '#next_btn',

            after:   onAfter,

            pagerAnchorBuilder: paginate


        });

});


                        function paginate(idx, el)


  {
    return '<div class="slide' + idx + '"></div>';
}


                    function onAfter() { 

var hasClass = $(".slide3").hasClass("activeSlide");
var hasTheClass = $(".slide0").hasClass("activeSlide");

if(hasClass == true) {
    $("#nav_slide").animate({"left": "-=226px"}, "fast");
}else if(hasTheClass == true) {
    $("#nav_slide").animate({"left": "0px"}, "fast");
}
```

}

Any ideas? I've been stumped for a while now!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Little clarification in problem statement would help

1) Are you having problems with "navigation buttons" or "pager buttons"?
2) What is "activeClass" . Do you mean "activeSlide" that gets appended to pager(1,2,3..) elements?
3) Please paste HTML & CSS , if these are relevant.

PS: Since the pager elements are links to slides, I would recommend using <a> instead of <div> tags.

```
function paginate(idx, el) {
                return '<a href="#">'+ (idx + 1) +'</a>';
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
I've changed to using a tags instead of divs, good call.


I was in a rush when I added in question, sorry for the errors. 
To clarify:

I'm having an issue with the "activeSlide" class that get's appended to the pager elements. 

HTML & CSS aren't really relevant. What's happening is, when the page loads, the cycle starts normally, but the pager buttons aren't taking the activeSlide class. The activeSlide class remains on the first slide until one of the pager is clicked. 

Once a pager is clicked, it starts running properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can think of 2 possible reasons
1)What is your implementation of 'onAfter' method? The observed quirk could be the result of some error in this method's implementation. Please paste the code for 'onAfter'
2)Browser quirk: What browser and what version are your using to test?

@Sreenath 
$(document).ready(function(){ //handler });
AND
$(function(){ //handler });
are equivalents. So they wont create any difference
[link](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I've posted the function in the question. I'm using chrome to test, but i also checked ie and ff, it's happening across the board. The 'onAfter' function is checking whether or not the pager item has the 'activeSlide' class. If the fourth pager item has the class, the left position animates. There are only 3 pagers shown at a time, so once it hits the fourth, the left position moves to display the remaining 3. This functionality is incomplete, but that's another story. Any more ideas? Thanks again for the input.

Comment: By plugging in updateActivePagerLink ,we should be alert in order (0,1,2..) . 
$("#slider").cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                timeout: 4000,
                pause: 1,
                pager: '#nav_slide',
                prev: '#prev2',
                next: '#next2',

                after: onAfter,

                pagerAnchorBuilder: paginate,
                updateActivePagerLink: function (pager, currSlide, clsName) {
                    alert(currSlide);
                }
            });

If this order does not appear,something is wrong. Let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after plugging it in, i'm only getting '0' to alert. I noticed in the example you put in your comment, you're using id's and not classes, will this affect the functionality at all? If I use the pager links, they proper numbers alert though.

Comment: Since currentSlide does not change(0,1,2..), it confirms that 'activeSlider' class will not append to each element.
Using 'Class' or 'id' does not matter as long as we select the element that we intend.
I guess you are putting the code in a different context than I do and hence you are facing this issue (contd..)

Comment: (contd..)
To solve this problem, do the following
1) Create a new HTML page.
2) Put all the relevant code in it (HTML,CSS,JQuery)
3) Validate it in a browser and confirm that you still see the weird behavior
4) Pass this HTML page to me.

I will try to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm just heading out of the office for 30 minutes, but will do this as soon as I get back.

Comment: So the plot thickens, I recreated what I had in a new html page, but it works fine. I'm going to assume the only other variable here is some kind of conflicting js somewhere?

Comment: Let me know what happens. We can document that as an answer.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what's causing the problem, it will probably take me a while. I'm using quite a bit of js on the site.

Comment: Sorry for the hiatus, the issue ended up resolving itself, and I have no idea how or why. This one's solved for the time being. Thanks again to everyone who answered!